# Proving a set theory equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A\subset B\cup C$, $A\cap B\neq \emptyset, A\cap C\neq \emptyset$ and $A\cap B \cap C = \emptyset$.
>
> Prove that $(A \cap B)^C=C \cup A^C$.

I've got an idea on how to prove this but can't quite write it down completely. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Let $x \in C \cup A^C $.
   By De Morgan's law $(A \cap B)^C=A^C \cup B^C$. Thus if $x \in A^C$ we have $x \in A^C \cup B^C$. If $x \in C$ we have $x \in B^C$ because $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, so $x \in A^C \cup B^C$.
   So we have $C \cup A^C \subset (A \cap B)^C$.
2. Let $x \in (A \cap B)^C = A^C \cup B^C.$
   If $x \in A^C$, $x \in C \cup A^C.$

We still have to prove that if $x \in B^C$, $x\in C \cup A^C$. This is the part I'm not so sure about.

I drew some diagrams of the situation and figured it should be enough to prove: if $x \in B^C$ then $x \in A \cap C$ or $x \in A^C$.

Comment: Why do you say that $B$ and $C$ are disjoint?

Comment: As presently written, the claim is false. $(A\cap B)^c\subsetneq C\cup A^c$ under the current conditions. Please check to make sure you've transcribed everything correctly.

Comment: Your hypotheses as stated are satisfied when $A = B = C$ and they are non-empty, but your conclusion doesn't hold then.

Comment: Transcription error: it's supposed to be $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$. $B$ and $C$ have to be disjoint because they both share elements with $A$ but $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: @user275211 That's incorrect. Take $A = \{1,2\}, B = \{1,4\} C = \{2,4\}$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321  Thanks for pointing that out. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the statement like $A^{C} \cup B^{C} = C \cup A^{C}$. Since $A^{C}$ is on both sides, we prove the statements $B^{C} \subset C \cup A^{C}$ and $C \subset A^{C} \cup B^{C}$.

1. $x \in B^{C}$, then if $x \in C^{C}$, it follows $x \in B^{C} \cap C^{C} \subset A^{C}$, by the first claim. Otherwise $x \in C \subset C \cup A^{C}$.
2. $x \in C$, then if $x \in B$, then since $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$, $x \in A^{C} \subset A^{C} \cup B^{C}$. Otherwise $x \in B^{C} \subset A^{C} \cup B^{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach runs into a problem. Consider $A=\{1,2\},$ $B=\{0,1\},$ $C=\{0,2\}.$ Note that $A,B,C$ satisfy the hypotheses (and the conclusion), but $B$ and $C$ are *not disjoint*!

Here's another (arguably better) way to go. First of all, since $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset,$ then $A\cap B$ and $C$ are disjoint, and so $C\subseteq(A\cap B)^c,$ as you should be able to prove. Also, $A^c\subseteq(A\cap B)^c,$ as you showed, and so $C\cup A^c\subseteq(A\cap B)^c.$

Similarly, $A$ is disjoint from $B\cap C,$ so since $$A\subseteq B\cup C=(B\cap C)\cup(B^c\cap C)\cup(B\cap C^c),$$ then $$A\subseteq(B^c\cap C)\cup(B\cap C^c),$$ and so $$A\cap C^c\subseteq B\cap C^c\subseteq B.$$ Since we certainly have $A\cap C^c\subseteq A,$ then $$A\cap C^c\subseteq A\cap B.$$ From this, we can show that $$(A\cap B)^c\subseteq(A\cap C^c)^c.$$ Can you justify these claims and take it from there?